# Gradle sync failed: Unable to find v8 package

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle, v8

I've installed the library `react-native-v8` to solve a problem on the library `react-native-reanimated` like the answer on this GitHub issue: [Click here to Open it](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/3570#issuecomment-1247366391).

Now I'm having the following error on the Android Studio Event Log:
[image]

I'd like some help with this issue, like, how to install the v8 package.

My Project Info:

```
System:
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.22000
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
    Memory: 4.98 GB / 31.90 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.17.0 - ~\AppData\Local\Temp\yarn--1666256124827-0.2926777437685064\node.CMD
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - ~\AppData\Local\Temp\yarn--1666256124827-0.2926777437685064\yarn.CMD
    npm: 8.15.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    Watchman: 20220821.200817.0 - C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\watchman.EXE
  SDKs:
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 31, 32, 33
      Build Tools: 30.0.2, 30.0.3, 31.0.0, 32.0.0, 32.1.0, 33.0.0
      System Images: android-33 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-33 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64
      Android NDK: Not Found
    Windows SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335
    Visual Studio: Not Found
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.15 - C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\javac.EXE
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17 => 17.0.2
    react-native: 0.68.3 => 0.68.3
    react-native-windows: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer that maybe works for those who are looking for, follow the steps on the documentation: https://npm.io/package/react-native-v8